# How can I transfer UVs from a source to a target using Animation Nodes?

Tags: uv, animation-nodes

I'm trying to manipulate mesh data of an object using animation nodes. While the manipulation of the data works just fine, I always lose the UV maps when generating the output object. I've provided a simplified Blend file here:

[image]

This is a screenshot from it:

[image: AN Copy UV]

So basically, all I want to do is preserve the already existing UVs from the source object, and add them to the target. Even the Data Transfer modifier does not provide a solution here, as AN constantly rebuilds the Target object.

A solution where I could easily generate new UV coordinates on the target would also fit my needs.

Comment: The feature is not available in Animation Nodes 2.0 and before. But it is available in 2.1 through the construct mesh node. (2.1 is still under development).

Comment: @OmarAhmad I'll try compiling 2.1 and report back if that works out for me, thanks!

Comment: @OmarAhmad I've compiled it successfully and threw in the 'construct mesh' node. Use UVs is checked. Under 'UV Map Names' I can also see the correct name of the map when using the 'Mesh Info' node. But how do I set it on the output object? 'Combine Mesh' and 'Mesh Object Output' both don't offer any UV related settings.

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: @OmarEmara I am using AN 2.2 (B 2.83) and i do not see a construct mesh node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After constructing the mesh while using UVs. You just have to output it using the mesh object output node.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, it opened up a lot of possibilities! I'm impressed by the performance of the replicate mesh node.

Comment: I can't find this node, I see the load uvs option in the "mesh object input" But is a boolean socket. In the docs there is not much info.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch This node was removed in recent version. So just use the *Mesh Object Input* node.